# Upgrading my build agent to .Net 4.6.1 did not work

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, build-agent

So, I tried to upgrade my TFS 2015 to allow project with .NET 4.6.1.

I downloaded the [Targeting Pack](http://getdotnet.azurewebsites.net/target-dotnet-platforms.html) for .NET 4.6.1, ran it, restarted the server, ran my build configuration for the build agent by overwriting the old settings, and started my builds.

Now non of them will build :(

I think I miss setting a parameter somewhere.
This is my agent, which is registered, but never requested (for some odd reason):

[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: What does "none of them will build" mean? Are you getting a specific error?

Comment: I have multiple projects (I forgot to specify), and none of them can build. And no, I don't get any errors - the best I get is a 'waiting for build agent' when I manually queue a build.

Comment: Did you just mean not only the .NET 4.6.1 project but all others can't build on the agent?

Comment: No projects - not matter the target version - will build.

Comment: Is there any error message when you queue the build?

Answer (score 0):

According to your **agent.version** `1.95.3,` seems you are using TFS2015 update3 which should definitely support  .Net 4.6.1.  And the system capabilities of your agent looks okay except the **Number_OF_PROCESSOR**. Your value is 1, but usually the default is 8. Did you manually change the value during the configure?

Recommend you follow below way to narrow down this issue:

1. First check in  that if the build server is available and enabled in
   TFS at `https://YOURCOMPANYNAME:8080/tfs/_admin/_AgentQueue`, and
   your build agent should be “Green”.
2. Make sure the agent is in **interactive mode**.
3. Try to change a domain account which is a member of the **Build
   Agent    Service Accounts group** and belongs to "Agent Pool Service
   Account"    role, to see whether the agent would work or not.
4. Double check whether there are some Firewall interface block the
   build, try to disable all related settings.

If it's still not work, delete that agent and **re-deploy a new one** following the detail steps in [this  article](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/admin/agents/v1-windows).  You can also go through below similar questions to check if there is some useful info :

- [TFS 2015 On-premise issues](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/pt-BR/56ce3349-5eed-43ce-97f6-f58eec82072e/tfs-2015-onpremise-issues?forum=tfsbuild)
- [TFS 2015 build vNext - hangs with "Waiting for console output from
  an agent..."](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1a6499ee-150b-400a-9fed-1f681e762ce4/tfs-2015-build-vnext-hangs-with-waiting-for-console-output-from-an-agent?forum=tfsbuild)
- [TFS 2015 Build agent won't start](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f0c15ae6-8843-4a57-97df-b43c9a79a054/tfs-2015-build-agent-wont-start?forum=tfsbuild)